# Android studio 3.6 canary 6 not start just loading

Tags: android-studio, flutter, beta-testing

I have download the latest Android studio 3.6 canary 6 first time it was working fine but when starting again it was not started just loading.

I have tried with open android studio with terminal, extract android studio again on the new folder but still, it was not working.

I have installed the following library using this command

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

When I was tried with terminal then it will be giving following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.flutter.actions.FlutterNewProjectAction PluginClassLoader[io.flutter, 38.2.4] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@8a0a427
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.instantiate(ActionManagerImpl.java:153)
    ... 20 more
2019-08-22 11:25:54,657 [   5136]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Android Studio 3.6 Canary 6  Build #AI-192.5587.17.36.5787298 
2019-08-22 11:25:54,657 [   5136]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_202-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-08-22 11:25:54,657 [   5136]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - OS: Linux 
2019-08-22 11:25:54,657 [   5136]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Plugin to blame: Flutter version: 38.2.4 
2019-08-22 11:25:54,657 [   5136]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Last Action:  
2019-08-22 11:30:52,285 [ 302764]   WARN - dea.sdk.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80'
```

I need to resolve this issue.
Can anyone share knowledge with me? Appreciated in advance.

Comment: so i assume you want to create a new project (`io.flutter.actions.FlutterNewProjectAction`)? tried to create a new project with `flutter create` command?

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the reply. 
I just want to start Android studio nothing else just update Android studio with 3.6 Canary 6

Comment: so where does `FlutterNewProjectAction` come from? it triggers while starting android studio?

Comment: yes It will occur when start Android studio

Comment: @TestingTesting Did you able to resolve this issue? Facing same problem in my Mac. In my linux its working fine.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have installed that flutter plug-in, as it appears to be incompatible. Not sure if there is any CLI switch for kind of safe-mode (with plug-ins disabled). Just use a stable version, problem solved.

Comment: The same happened to me, I removed flutter plugin manually from disk (on mac ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview3.6/flutter* folders) and then was able to start the IDE. Plugin paths in different systems - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519